# Simple regular expression using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a regular expression for below string. The dynamic portion (i.e. for which expression needed is in bold text)

The mail system

> **email address**: host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] said:
>
> 550 Requested action not taken:
>
> **mailbox unavailable** (in reply to RCPTTO command)

Basically I want that my regexp search for email and the "mailbox unavailable".

So it will search for mail first and then search for the string "mailbox unavailable".

How can I do this? I need to use `preg_match` php function for this.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but will this work?

**Regular Expression**

```
/email\saddress:(.*?)mailbox\sunavailable(.*)$/si
```

**Example**

```
<?php

$text = <<<EndText
email address: host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] said:

550 Requested action not taken:

mailbox unavailable (in reply to RCPTTO command)
EndText;

preg_match('/email\saddress:(.*?)mailbox\sunavailable(.*)$/si', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

**Output**

```
array
  0 => string 'email address: host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] said:



550 Requested action not taken:



mailbox unavailable (in reply to RCPTTO command)' (length=142)
  1 => string ' host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] said:



550 Requested action not taken:



' (length=80)
  2 => string ' (in reply to RCPTTO command)' (length=29)
```